# Cross Apply equivalent in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I'm very new to SQL. I'm trying to JOIN two tables, if JOIN returns null, then join on a default value.

Student:

```
student_id     s_major    name   
------------ ---------- --------
  123           CS        Alice   
  456           CS1       Bob
  789           CS2       Eve
```

Major:

```
  m_major      description
--------- ---------------------
   CS        Computer Science             
   CS1       Computer Science 1
```

And I'm hoping to get a result table like this:

```
student_id     s_major  m_major   name     description
------------- -------- --------- ------- -----------------
  123           CS       CS       Alice    Computer Science
  456           CS1      CS1      Bob      Computer Science 1
  789           CS2      CS       Eve      Computer Science
```

**All variables are of type char

For example, 'CS2', consider the '2' of as a major option, but there's no description for this major option. So the default value for this major option will simply be the major, 'CS' in this case.

I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818605/if-join-returns-null-then-join-on-default-row) suggesting using CROSS APPLY. But it seems there's no CROSS APPLY in DB2. So I'm trying to see if there's any equivalent or work around.

Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at the CROSS JOIN. https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks for you comment. I did check out the CROSS JOIN. But CROSS JOIN is giving me more rows than I need. I'm not sure what to put in WHERE clause to filter the result table

Comment: How do you define default values exactly? Are they some predefined constants or are they derived somehow from these tables? Why the row with id=789 has name=Casey and not Eve (as in Student)?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Thanks for you comment. For example, CS2, consider the '2' of as a major option, but there's no description for this major option. So the default value for this major option will simply be the major, 'CS' in this case. And sorry, id = 789, name = Casey was a mistake. I'll fix that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH 
  STUDENT (student_id, s_major, name) AS
(
VALUES
  (123, 'CS ', 'Alice')  
, (456, 'CS1', 'Bob')
, (789, 'CS2', 'Eve')
)
, MAJOR (m_major, description) AS
(
VALUES
  ('CS ', 'Computer Science')            
, ('CS1', 'Computer Science 1')
)
SELECT S.student_id, S.s_major
, NVL (M.m_major, M2.m_major) AS m_major
, S.name
, NVL (M.description, M2.description) AS description
FROM STUDENT S
LEFT JOIN MAJOR M ON M.M_MAJOR = S.S_MAJOR
CROSS JOIN TABLE
(
SELECT * 
FROM MAJOR M2
WHERE M2.m_major = SUBSTR (S.s_major, 1, 2)
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
) M2
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=104206ea4f5b3acb8d2837c6aae74520) link.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This helps me. Just one short question, is it possible to check if `m_major = substr(S.s_major,1,2)` inside M2? I tried but it complained `NOT VALID IN THE CONTEXT WHERE IT IS USED`

Comment: You have to use a `TABLE` keyword to have an ability to specify expressions with outer table column references. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks again! This is exactly what I'm looking for. I just don't understand why `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` is in use here. The results seem the same with or without this line of statement. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: And you might want to change the alias M2 to M1 or something else in the CROSS JOIN statement.

Comment: `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` is to get the only row with defaults for a given one. It's not needed for this example, but might be needed for a common case, when more than 1 row may be returned from M2 for a given row in S with such a condition. So, it's just for safety.