# SQL - Join on value OR default value

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables with data similar to the following:

**business:**

```
id company_name industry
1  test         123
```

**industry_benchmark_ratio:**

```
id code year value
1  00   2021 1.1
2  00   2020 1.2
3  111  2021 1.11 
4  222  2021 1.12 
5  222  2021 1.12
```

I want to select a business and join the ratio table on the industry code, if there is no matching code however, I want to join on the default '00' + year value, so I'm looking for something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM business b
JOIN industry_benchmark_ratio ibr ON (
     (b.industry = ibr.industry and year = 2021) OR
     (ibr.industry = 00 and year = 2021)
)
```

COALESCE comes to mind but I'm not quite sure how to apply it here.

Comment: This is similar to the question I've asked, you could check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68446075/8644910

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the direction you are headed to solve this. Join the second table in twice and coalesce to get what you need:

```
SELECT b.*, COALESCE(ibr1.value, ibr2.value)
FROM business b
    INNER JOIN industry_benchmark_ratio ibr1 ON 
     b.industry = ibr2.industry and ibr1.year = 2021 
    INNER JOIN industry_benchmark_ratio ibr2 ON
     ibr2.industry = 00 and ibr2.year = 2021
```